# Vim with foreign QWERTZ keyboard

Tags: vim, keyboard-layout

Vim is optimized for the standard US keyboard:

[image]

If we want to use it with the following QWERTZ keyboard (common in Austria and Germany):

[image]

**What should we do?** (aside from using the US keyboard map, of course)

Especially problematic are the `:`, `;`, `/`, `?` keys and the backtick, which are used very often and on the QWERTZ keyboard above difficult to reach and pretty counter-intuitive. For example, after pressing `f`,`x`searching for the *next* 'x' with `;` involves pressing the *shift* key.

Maybe the following modifications in `~/.vimrc` are a good idea?

```
nnoremap ü  ` 
nnoremap ä  / 
nnoremap Ä  ?  
nnoremap ö  ; 
nnoremap Ö  :
nnoremap :  <Nop>
```

(and the same lines with `vnoremap` instead of `nnoremap`)

Of course, one also has to disable deadkeys (e.g. so we can use `ctrl`+`^` for switching buffers). Exchanging caps-lock with escape is also helpful. So we insert this in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/de`:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "switch_esc_caps" {
    include "de(nodeadkeys)"
    name[Group1] = "Germany B";
    key <CAPS> { [ Escape ] } ;
};
```

And put in the directory `~/.Xsession.d` the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

setxkbmap -layout de -variant switch_esc_caps
```

Everything ok that way? At least it seems to work... is there a cleaner approach?

Now there are still problems:

1. The backtick is also a mark for the last position, is there a way to
   redefine this? So that `ü` becomes the mark for the last position and we get back to the last position by pressing `ü`,`ü`?
2. Though pressing `ä` opens the search, in substitution commands we still have to use the `/`.

   Maybe this is not a good idea, but in sed one can choose a different delimiter than `/`, like:

   `'abc' | sed -e 's-abc-def-g'`

   Is something similar possible in vim?